# .htaccess rewrite rule with get params

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to be able to rewrite `http://example.com/staging/details/?postid=23` so that it becomes `http://example.com/staging/grandhotelterduin`

I am not sure how the .htaccess rule should be?

I have came up with something like this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteRule ^grandhotelterduin/(.*)$ ./details/?postid=23 [L,NC]
```

I am not sure I am doing this correctly, can you plz help

I want it such that the `http://example.com/staging/grandhotelterduin/` get redirected to `http://example.com/staging/details/?postid=23` but the url that appears in the browser is `http://example.com/staging/grandhotelterduin

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^grandhotelterduin$ /staging/details/?postid=23 [L]
```

It will give you the following URL:

`http://sheetz.nl/grandhotelterduin`

EDIT:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /staging/details/?postid=([0-9]+)  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /staging/grandhotelterduin [L,R]
```

Comment: could you please check the rule again

Comment: You can try my edit, but when  I tested my previous rule, it worked. Make sure the rule is at the top of your `.htaccess` and that your cache is cleared.